# Processing multiple messages in a single queue job with Laravel Queue

Tags: laravel, queue, webhooks, jobs, laravel-6

In my project there are two jobs that regularly download XML files from multiple domains and then parse them to discover changed nodes. These nodes are then individually saved to a database and enqueued to be processed by yet another job where they are sent via a webhook to another app.

The foreign API supports multiple nodes from different origins being sent in a single request. So in the webhook Job I would like to be able to retrieve up to a fixed number of messages off of the queue.

Is there a way to do this with Laravel's Queue system? I have not been able to find it in the documentation.

To make this clearer I will provide a simple example:

Three sepearate files are downloaded twice. The two versions of the three files are compared and the changed nodes are extracted. File 1 has 7 changes, File 2 has 8, File 3 has 4. The foreign API supports up to 10 changes. I would like to then send on the first webhook call: The 7 from file 1, plus the first 3 changes from file 2, then on the second webhook: the remaining 5 changes from file 2 and the 4 changes from file 3.

Comment: Can you share more details about your project?

Comment: And on stackoverflow you have to provide code, so we have some way of reproducing your problem. I case of your problem im very intereseted in how you create your jobs and why you do not just bundle them togheter for creating the bundles you want :)

Comment: @mrhn  I don't *just* bundle them together it's because I need to bundle together messages from different message producers. I've updated the question with an example. I think you are mistaken about providing code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask: "Not all questions benefit from including code". There is no bug to reproduce in this instance, my code works as is. I'm asking whether certain undocumented or poorly documented functionality exists in Laravel so as to improve my code's performance.

Comment: But it is hard to understand your problem if we can't see what you are trying to do. Since no activity on the question yet, probably others feel the same.